# Whitespaces are not allowed around % sign in namelist input file for derived type

Tags: fortran

Here's test code:

```
program testcase
    implicit none

    integer :: ios, lu
    type derived
        integer :: a
    end type derived
    type (derived) :: d

    namelist /test/ d

    lu = 3
    open (lu, file = 'test.dat', status='old', iostat=ios)
    read (lu, nml = test, iostat=ios)
    if (ios /= 0) then
        write (*, *) 'error!'
    else
        write (*, *) 'good!', d % a
    endif
end program testcase
```

This program reads an input file `test.dat` which contains a namelist for `test` whose type is a derived type `derived`.

When I try next content for `test.dat` it works fine(it prints `good! 7`):

```
&test
    d%a = 7
/
```

However, with next content, I get an error:

```
&test
    d % a = 7
/

Equal sign must follow namelist object name d
```

What's different is the whitespaces around `%` sign for component access in derived type.

I've tested with GNU Fortran(gfortran) 5.3.0. I also heard from my colleague that same problem occurred with latest Intel Fortran compiler. He also insisted that the old version of Intel Fortran compiler worked fine with both cases.

Is this behavior is normal? That is, does the standard forbid whitespaces around `%` in namelist input file,  while whitespaces around `%` are allowed in source code?

Or, is this a bug of compiler or implementation of standard library?

Comment: I can confirm that `gfortran` v4.4.7 gives an error if there are spaces around the `%` character, whereas intel fortran compiler (v12.1.3 and v16.0.3) correctly read the namelist.

Comment: I've caught the error message, it's code 5010, and message is "Equal sign must follow namelist object name d"

Comment: @chw21 Thank you. Your information helped me find some pages which state this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found some references which mention this problem.

From http://technion.ac.il/doc/intel/compiler_f/main_for/lref_for/source_files/pghnminp.htm ,

> &group-name object = value [, object = value] .../
>
> ...
>
> object
>
> Is the name (or subobject designator) of an entity defined in the
>   NAMELIST declaration of the group name. **The object name must not
>   contain embedded blanks** except within the parentheses of a subscript
>   or substring specifier. Each object must be contained in a single
>   record.

Another one from http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3693-51/html-S-3693-51/i5lylchri.html ,

> 2.13.1.1. Names in Name-value Pairs
>
> ...
>
> - **A name in an input record must not contain embedded blanks.** A name in the name-value pair can be preceded or followed by one or more
>     blanks.

So, apparently, it seems that whitespaces in name are never allowed.